# How to view other users' files? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, files, users

Can I view files from other users on the same local machine if I am root? If so, how?

Comment: I am root. I think I figured it out, navigated to /home/username as root. LoL

Comment: @JeffSchaller why is this off-topic?

Comment: @user1271772 the stock message (which may not be visible to you) says "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers." -- and that's the case here, as you can see by axxic3's previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can $ sudo su and you're effectively a root user now. 
And, Go / (root) and see /home folder can find all the user on the machine.

Comment: Out the question , for shared is it possible to disable root privilege for regular user , let say users have access to  remote server system

Comment: $ vim /etc/sudoers                                                                                    $ sudo deluser USERNAME sudo. This will take sudo access away from the particular user.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to a different user account from root is not safe by default.

It's much safer to directly browse into the desired directory as the root user than use `su` or `sudo` to switch users since the latter allows an infected user to *automatically* execute arbitrary commands as root via the TIOCSTI ioctl by pushing commands onto root's tty.

For instance, suppose there's a binary `hacksu` that takes advantage of the TIOCSTI ioctl and that an intruder has modified the infected user account [user]'s .bashrc to execute this binary when the shell starts.

```
$ tail -n3 /home/[user]/.bashrc
echo hi
/opt/hacksu -- $'echo "hello world" >> /tmp/file1\nfg'
echo bye
$ _
```

Then, when root uses `su` on the infected user, the infected user gets to execute arbitrary commands as root.

```
root@host:~# su - [user]
```

The 8 following lines print themselves to the terminal without user interaction since sourcing .bashrc is automatic.

```
echo "hello world" >> /tmp/file
1
fg
[1]+  Stopped                 su - [user]
root@host:~# echo "hello world" >> /tmp/file1
root@host:~# fg
su - [user]
bye
```

Now, root realizes something is up and closes the [user] shell to check out what [user]'s .bashrc did.

```
[user]@host:~$ logout
root@host:~# ll /tmp/file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Apr 15 00:47 /tmp/file1  # owned by root (!)
root@host:~# cat -v /tmp/file1
hello world
root@host:~# # oops ..
```

In the above scenario, [user] has just written to an arbitrary file as the root user. In practice, the executed commands could do anything root could. Imagine, for instance, if the `hacksu` binary had been called to modify `/etc/shadow` instead.

The source for the POC `hacksu` binary can be found at https://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/. Don't switch to another user as root unless you've worked around the threat of an infected user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
# su user
```

as root to become that user and see his files

Comment: isn't this supposed to leave traces if you work as that user? like history items etc